# Не срабатывает условие в if

Tags: php

**Задача:** Дан инпут и кнопка. В этот инпут вводится дата рождения в формате '31.12'. По нажатию на кнопку выведите знак зодиака пользователя.

**Решение:**

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Введите дату: dd.mm">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```php
$signs = [1 => "Козерог", "Водолей", "Рыбы", "Овен", "Телец", "Близнецы", "Рак", "Лев", "Девы", "Весы", "Скорпион", "Стрелец"];
$signs_date = [1 => 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23];

if (isset($_REQUEST['date'])) {

        $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
        $date = explode('.', $date);
        $day = $date[0];
        $month = $date[1]; 

        if (substr($month, 0, 1) == 0) {                
                $month = substr($month, 1, 2);
        } 

        if ($day > $signs_date[$month]) {
                $a = $signs[$month + 1];

        } else  {
                $a = $signs[$month];
        }

        if ($a == 13) {
                echo $signs[1];
        } else {
                echo $a;
        }
}
```

**Проблема:** Если подставить 31.12, то условие `php if ($day > $signs_date[$month])` не срабатывает. Почему это происходит?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У Вас в `$signs[$month + 1];` При использовании последнего месяца появляется 13-ая позиция(ключ), а в массиве их только 12. 
Используйте это:

```php
$signs = [1 => "Козерог", "Водолей", "Рыбы", "Овен", "Телец", "Близнецы", "Рак", "Лев", "Девы", "Весы", "Скорпион", "Стрелец"];
$signs_date = [1 => 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23];

if (isset($_REQUEST['date'])) {

    $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
    $date = explode('.', $date);
    $day = $date[0];
    $month = $date[1];

    if (substr($month, 0, 1) == 0) {
        $month = substr($month, 1, 2);
    }
    if ($day > $signs_date[$month]) {
        if ($month == "12"){
            $month = "0";
        }
        $a = $signs[$month + 1];
    } else  {
        $a = $signs[$month];
    }
    if ($a == 13) {
        echo $signs[1];
    } else {
        echo $a;
    }
}
?>


<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Введите дату: dd.mm">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Денис, спасибо, но это не отвечает на мой вопрос. Я не понимаю, почему if ($day > $signs_date[$month]) - само условие не выполняется, ведь 31 > 23. Но оно не выполняется и $a не становиться == 13.

Comment: @Andy_Frost я ответил на Ваш вопрос. Это условие выполняется, но в массиве `signs` всего 12 элементов.  в `$a = $signs[$month + 1];` Вы ищете значение в этом массиве по ключу, который получаете ранее `$month = substr($month, 1, 2);`. Когда Вы указываете 12 месяц - Ваша функция прибавляет к месяцу +1, получается 13. А такого элемента в массиве `signs` нет. Их всего там 12.